# add double quotes to strings in array

Tags: jenkins, groovy

```
def names = [lucas,Fred, Mary]

for (i in names) {
   println i
}
```

I want to remove the white space, and add double quotes to each strings in the array using groovy.

**expected output:**

```
"lucas",
"Fred",
"Mary"
```

Comment: Your question is not valid groovy. Please edit it so it at least is valid

Answer (score 2):

I guess if *names* is a string array that could work

```
def names = ["lucas", "Fred", "Mary"]
println names.collect{"\"${it}\""}.join(",\n")
```

Comment: Actually that is static, can't double quotes within the array itself  to ["lucas", "Fred", "Mary"] . Looking for a solution without without making a changes to the existing array.

Comment: This example will work no matter of array definition and actually don't change array

Comment: Does it work when i have def names = [lucas, Fred, Mary] ? instead of def names = ["lucas", "Fred", "Mary"] ?

Comment: That's not valid groovy 

Comment: It’s valid if lucas, Fred, etc is constants which defined before and will work.

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't seem to be the case here

Comment: Yes, since the values are constant . doest it work the below ;

Comment: def names = [lucas, Fred, Mary]
println names.collect{"\"${it}\""}.join(",\n")

Comment: error: 
No such property: lucas for class: _GroovyUserScript_

Comment: That's because the code you have shown us isn't valid groovy 

Answer (score 0):

you could use string instead of array

```
def names = "lucas,Fred,Mary"

for (i in names.split(',')) {
   println '"'+i+'"'
}
```

another way (but could be tricky because you play with variables):

```
public class NamesBinding extends Binding{
    @Delegate Binding delegate;
    public Object getVariable(String name) {
        //when variable declared - return the value, otherwise return the quoted name
        return delegate.hasVariable(name) ? delegate.getVariable(name) : "${groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(name)}"
    }
}

this.setBinding(new NamesBinding(delegate:this.getBinding()))

def names = [lucas,Fred,Mary]

for (i in names) {
   println i
}
```